# How to return data from SQL Server using Entity Framework within date range C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have to return data from SQL Server based on a date range (`startDate` and `endDate`). The start date condition works fine, but `endDate` returns greater records than the end date specified.

Consider following example. Thank you for your insights :

```
var patientEvents = from pEvents in _context.PatientDataEvents 
                    join computers in _context.Computers  
                         on pEvents.machineName equals computers.machineName
                    where (fin == null || pEvents.fin == fin) &&
                          (start == null || pEvents.time >= DateTime.Parse(start)) &&
                          (end == null || pEvents.time <= DateTime.Parse(end).AddDays(1))
                    orderby pEvents.time descending
                    select new PatientsEventsAdmin
                               {
                                   Date = pEvents.time,
                                   Fin = pEvents.fin,
                                   Computer = computers.machineName,
                                   Location = computers.name
                               };

return patientEvents.Take(display).ToList();
```

The query generated by EF is :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [pEvents].[time], [pEvents].[fin], 
[computers].[machineName], [computers].[name]
FROM [PatientDataEvents] AS [pEvents]
INNER JOIN [Computers] AS [computers] ON [pEvents].[machineName] = [computers].[machineName]
WHERE [pEvents].[time] <= @__AddDays_0
ORDER BY [pEvents].[time] DESC',N'@__p_1 int,@__AddDays_0 
datetime2(7)',@__p_1=100,@__AddDays_0='2017-08-24 15:36:06'
```

It returns records with this date time as well 2017-08-23 17:31:38, instead it should have last result with 2017-08-23 15:36:06

Comment: what locality is your date stored as? If it is UTC then you need to apply offset in your query

Comment: `2017-08-23 17:31:38` is posterior to `2017-08-23 15:36:06`, exactly what you asked for..

Comment: If you want the first, and no the last in the range, use `orderby  pEvents.time ascending`

Comment: also, I don't see `start` only `end` --> `[pEvents].[time] <= @__AddDays_0`

Comment: even with start, the result returns in same way

Comment: So you pass `2017-08-23 15:36:06`, then `.AddDays(1)` adds 1 day to that and the record with `2017-08-23 17:31:38` falls within this range. Where does the surprise come in?

Comment: are you sure that is the correct query you are looking at? I don't see the filter for `pEvents.fin` at all in the query. Do a `patientEvents.ToString()` and paste the content in to your question.